# How to create a list of methods and type in scala

Tags: scala

I would like to create this kind of scala list:

```
List(("Att1", getAtt1(), Int),
     ("Att2", getAtt2(), BigDecimal),
     ("Att3", getAtt3(), Long))
```

getAtt1, getAtt2 and getAtt3 come from a Java object imported in Scala. I use the third parameter of the list to know the conversion. For example, getAtt3() returns an Int and my List tells me that I need to convert it to a Long.

I use Scala 2.11.8.

Do you have any Idea?

Comment: This is a good candidate for a case class no?

Comment: Indeed but How can I place a method in my case class field?

Comment: @a.moussa you can use function types:

`case class Conv(name: String, get: () => Int, convert: Int => Long)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed, like mentioned in comments, use a class to solve this problem. I'd go for a class with 2 type parameters and conversion method. Something like this:

```
> case class Attribute[Original, Target](name: String, value: () => Original)(converter: Original => Target) {
    def convert = converter(value())
  }
defined class Attribute

> Attribute("three", () => 3)(_.toLong).convert
res11: Long = 3L
```

Please notice I've separated the `converter` parameter of the case class into its own parameter block. This is a common trick in Scala to help with type inference. Now you can define the conversion from `Int` to `Long` as just `_.toLong`. If you'd put the `converter` into the same parameter block, you'd have to specify the full type signature during instance creation: `Attribute("", () => 3, (i: Int) => i.toLong)`.

Comment: very helpfull, it is what I was looking for :)